# What does "to make quite a show about going into action" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It appears that he's **making quite a show about going into action**.

Source: Dragon Ball Z, Vegeta about his enemy Cell destroying everything around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can have two interpretations:

1. He is putting up significant resistance because he doesn't want to go into action. This would be tantamount to "making quite a fuss."
2. He is taking advantage of the situation to show off, make a big production of his going into action.

Comment: Just to be sure... I'll give you more context. Watch this (from 18:49 to 19:05): http://www.hulu.com/watch/333197

Comment: It's meaning No.2 - he's making a big spectacle with lights and flashes, etc.

Comment: Can we replace "about" in this sentence with "of"?

Comment: Yes, but it's not as idiomatic as "about," at least not in the US.